Use variable in custom policy screen to load style sheet
I would like to use a query string variable in my custom unified screen for Azure AD B2C to affect which styling sheet needs to be loaded. Something like this kind of URL:
https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/styles/{client_id}/images/LightstoneLogo.png

You can try dynamic page content.
"By using Azure AD B2C custom policies, you can send a parameter in the URL path, or a query string. By passing the parameter to your HTML endpoint, you can dynamically change the page content. For example, you can change the background image on the Azure AD B2C sign-up or sign-in page, based on a parameter that you pass from your web or mobile application. The parameter can be any claim resolver, such as the application ID, language ID, or custom query string parameter, such as campaignId."

Thanks for the reply @rbrayb. I have looked at the dynamic page content, I am just not sure how to use it exactly within the HTML of the page. I want to use the value of ClientId to determine from where should the stylesheet be loaded.

Claims resolver {OIDC:ClientId}

I have that inside my custom policy. I would like to know how to use it in the html of the page. Can I use it like this?

Or should I use Javascript to extract the value from the query string?
Your question concerned a URL. You can achieve this via the link above. The relying party will then create a URL based on clientID. You can then pick this parameter up from the query string. You can't put it inside the HTML yourself.

Thanks for the information @rbrayb. I ended up using the claims resolver together with Javascript to get the required value from the query string. here is my Javascript.
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var tenant = "";
if (url.searchParams.has("tenantId")) {
    tenant = url.searchParams.get("tenantId");
}
else {
    tenant = "default";
}
var styleSheet = 'url' + tenantId;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + styleSheet + "' />");

});
